# How do I solve my Jquery inArray seaching function problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have a simple Jquery problem. Here is a search bar button `#search_icon` which will show results after is clicked. The results will be shown in masonry with boxes with specified tags, in my example, they are "sci-fi" and "history" which are put in an array.

My problem is that after I searched either one of the tags in the array, the result of the second one is also "This category has been searched." Thanks for any clues.

```
$('#search_icon').click(function() {
    var sSearch = $('#search').val();
    var ans = new Array();
    ans[0] = 'sci-fi';
    ans[1] = 'history';

    sSearch = sSearch.split(" "); /*turn each word to a value in array and add them in an array*/
    $('#results > div').show();
    $.each(sSearch, function(i) {
        /*iterate function with each value in the array*/
        if ($.inArray($('#search').val().toLowerCase(), ans) > -1) {
            $('#results > div:not(:contains("' + sSearch[i] + '"))').hide();
            if ($('#records > div').find(":button").length) {
                /*.length check button element*/
                if ($('#records > div > button:contains("' + sSearch[i] + '")')) {
                    alert("This category has been searched.");
                    console.log(sSearch);
                } else {
                    $('#records > div').append('<button class="btn_default my-2 mr-2">' + sSearch[i] + '<span id="close_category" class="ml-2 cross"> &#10005;</span></button>');

                }
            } else {
                console.log("First button");
                $('#records > div').append('<button class="btn_default my-2 mr-2">' + sSearch[i] + '<span id="close_category" class="ml-2 cross"> &#10005;</span></button>');
                $('#search').val("");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, this category does not exists.");
        }
    });

    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var sSearch = this.value;
        sSearch = sSearch.split(" ");
        $.each(sSearch, function(i) {
            $('#results > div:contains("' + sSearch[i] + '")').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: We also need to see your HTML.

Comment: As a general rule, adding an one event listener inside another (`$('#search').keyup`) isn't a great idea. If the search icon is clicked multiple times, each keyup event will be handled that many times.

Comment: `$.inArray($('#search').val().toLowerCase(), ans)` doesn't seem right. The input field contains a space-separated list, and you're iterating over that list with `$.each()`. Why are you now searching for the entire input in `ans` rather than `sSearch[i]`?

Comment: I think what you want is `if (sSearch.some(s => ans.includes(s))`

Comment: @DBS I have commented the part of keyup function, but the problem has not been solved. Thanks.

Comment: As Barmar notes, the code does not make sense. You grab the value of `$("#search")` at the top of the function, split it on spaces, and then iterate through that array. Then for each of those values, you check **the entire value** of `$("#search")` against the answer array. That should be checking the value from the `sSearch` split result, which can be obtained by adding a second parameter to the `$.each()` call.

Comment: I suspect that below code is not written properly to check if the button tag contains text which is typed in an element which is defined as sSearch. Any idea? please.

if($('#records > div > button:contains("' + sSearch + '")')){
                                alert("This catergory has been searched.");

Comment: if($('#records > div > button:contains("' + sSearch[i] + '")').length > 0) seems work for the checking I wanted to do